# __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, variables, init, self

I am writing a bot to trade cryptocurrencies using bitvavo.com as my exchange. On their website, you can find an API section (https://docs.bitvavo.com/) with this bit of code:

```
from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo

bitvavo = Bitvavo('<APIKEY>', '<APISECRET>')
response = bitvavo.balance({})
for item in response:
  print(item)
```

However, when I copied and pasted this code into my IDE, it gave me the following error:

```
__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

When I tried just one variable inside the (), I noticed that the program ran, but Bitvavo.com game me an error due to not having the correct values: `(APIKEY, APISECRET)`, which is normal.

After some research, I found out that in most of the cases, it has something to do with the variable "self" (which does not show) already using one of the two variable spots inside the `Bitvavo()`. But as I didn't create this function myself due to it coming from the `from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo` section, I don't know how to fix this.

If anyone knows perhaps how to fix this and is willing to show me the solution or give an alternative to this, I would be really thankful. And if possible, please explain it in the most basic way ever because I'm dumb! :)

Comment: Share the full error details please.

Comment: Yes you're dumb. But you're not dumb because you made mistakes in your code, instead it's because you try to jump too far ahead of your knowledge. Take a few steps back. Read some books and tutorials, perhaps even take some classes. [The official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) is rather good, both for beginners and as a reference once you get better. Baby steps, friend, baby steps, and you'll soon be able to run. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the example(s) on the [Bitvavo API Github](https://github.com/bitvavo/python-bitvavo-api) page, you need to provide that information as a dictionary, rather than individual arguments.

```py
from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo
bitvavo = Bitvavo({
  'APIKEY': '<APIKEY>',
  'APISECRET': '<APISECRET>',
  'RESTURL': 'https://api.bitvavo.com/v2',
  'WSURL': 'wss://ws.bitvavo.com/v2/',
  'ACCESSWINDOW': 10000,
  'DEBUGGING': False
})
```

This came from the [readme here](https://github.com/bitvavo/python-bitvavo-api#rest-requests)

Hence it complains about too many arguments. It was only expecting 1 (other than the class's own `self` which is inserted automatically, hence a total of 2).

Comment: why did this get accepted today lmao

Answer (score 1):

The [`python_bitvavo_api`](https://github.com/bitvavo/python-bitvavo-api#getting-started) library class takes a single `dict` as it's argument, containing multiple params. You mean:

```
bitvavo = Bitvavo({'APIKEY': '<APIKEY>', 'APISECRET': '<APISECRET>' })
```

Comment: And I just spent daaays trying to fix it. Thank you so much, it works!